# Start Fragment via function in MainActivity

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragment, call

I'm trying to start a fragment programmatically. The function below works fine on its own. The problem here is, that I have to call the function from within another fragment. The call from the fragment to MainActivity works and is not the problem.

```
public void gotoFragment1(){
    Fragment1 fragment = new Fragment1();
    FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    transaction.replace(R.id.nav_host_fragment, fragment);
    transaction.addToBackStack(null);
    transaction.commit();
}
```

If I try to call the function from another fragment the app crashes with the following stacktrace:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: FragmentManager has not been attached to a host.
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.enqueueAction(FragmentManager.java:1727)
    at androidx.fragment.app.BackStackRecord.commitInternal(BackStackRecord.java:321)
    at androidx.fragment.app.BackStackRecord.commit(BackStackRecord.java:286)
    at com.fewo.info.MainActivity.gotoVeranstaltungen(MainActivity.java:134)
    at com.fewo.info.ui.home.HomeFragment$1.onClick(HomeFragment.java:53)
```

How can I change the fragment with this code beeing called from within another fragment?

Comment: When are you calling this code? Have you tried to use ```childFragmentManager``` instead of ```supportFragmentManager ```

Comment: fragment A call Fragment B via ActivityOne

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fragment A:

```
((ActivityOne) getActivity()).callFragmentB();
```

Activity One

```
public void callFragmentB(){
   //run your fragment transaction To B here
}
```

Answer (score 2):

if you want replace a fragment in `MainActivity` from other Fragments, you can do it in your fragment (No need to call function from `MainActivity`),
use this in your fragment:

```
getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
            .replace(R.id.nav_host_fragment, new Fragment1(), FragmentLoanList.class.getName()).addToBackStack(null)
            .commit();
```